# How to return 2 values from one method and use both values in one class?

Tags: java, android, return, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying out this code from Microsoft, however I wanted to combine the 2 features they made. One is analyzing image and one is detecting celebrities. However, I'm having a hard time on how will I return 2 values from one function. 
Here is the process method...

```
private String process() throws VisionServiceException, IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String model = "celebrities";

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());


    AnalysisResult v = this.client.describe(inputStream, 1);
    AnalysisInDomainResult m = this.client.analyzeImageInDomain(inputStream,model);

    String result = gson.toJson(v);
    String result2 = gson.toJson(m);

    Log.d("result", result);

    return result, result2;
}
```

And combine the 2 results with this method...

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);

    mEditText.setText("");
    if (e != null) {
        mEditText.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        this.e = null;
    } else {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        AnalysisResult result = gson.fromJson(data, AnalysisResult.class);
        //pang detect ng peymus...
        AnalysisInDomainResult result2 = gson.fromJson(data, AnalysisInDomainResult.class);

        //decode the returned result
        JsonArray detectedCelebs = result2.result.get("celebrities").getAsJsonArray();
        if(result2.result != null){
            mEditText.append("Celebrities detected: "+detectedCelebs.size()+"\n");
            for(JsonElement celebElement: detectedCelebs) {
                JsonObject celeb = celebElement.getAsJsonObject();
                mEditText.append("Name: "+celeb.get("name").getAsString() +", score" +
                        celeb.get("confidence").getAsString() +"\n");
            }
        }else {
            for (Caption caption: result.description.captions) {
                mEditText.append("Your seeing " + caption.text + ", confidence: " + caption.confidence + "\n");
            }
            mEditText.append("\n");
        }


       /* for (String tag: result.description.tags) {
            mEditText.append("Tag: " + tag + "\n");
        }
        mEditText.append("\n");
        mEditText.append("\n--- Raw Data ---\n\n");
        mEditText.append(data);*/
        mEditText.setSelection(0);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: either in an array or List (or other Collection), or through a composite Object

Comment: use a Map. and different keys for the values. E.gL map.put(result1,val1);map.put(result2,val2); return map;

Comment: I tried your suggestion @akshayapandey. Map.put(result, result);Map.put(result2, result2); but then, it has an error on put, saying "non-static method put(K, V) cannot be referenced from a static context. How to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Map map = new HashMap(); map.put......

Answer (score 7):

you can use. the parameter are two objects so can you can put everything

```
  final Pair<String, String> pair = Pair.create("1", "2");
  String a = pair.first;
  String b = pair.second;
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your suggestion, what should I return then after creating this, Pair.create("result", result);
        Pair.create("result2", result2);

Answer (score 4):

Simply use Bundle

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key_one", "your_first_value");
        bundle.putString("key_two", "your_second_value");
        return bundle;
```

You can add multiple values with different types in Bundle.In this case your method's return type should be Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

or `AbstractMap#SimpleEntry` (or as of Java-9 `Map#entry`)

You can always return two values via `Arrays.asList(one, two)` also